# ASP NET Core 5.0 not supported in Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-5.0

Hello i have a `ASP Net Core 5.0` web api which i am trying to deploy to `azure` and i can't because it says it is not yet supported.
However following the MSDN and similar threads ( when the same issue was valid for .NET Core 3.1) i understood that you can publish it with the option to be `self-contained`.
It still does not work:

**Application Logs**

[image]

**VStudio Publish**
[image]
Any idea on how to publish my application to azure ?

**Later Edit**
I forgot to mention all calls to my web api return a `404` message.

So if my
[indexurl] returns the microsoft page
[Indexurl]/[some path] returns `404` (which i understood from github is a `500` actually)

What should i understand ? The web api works , or it doesnt and where could the problem be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ASP NET Core 5.0 not supported in Azure

**After testing, azure webapp currently supports ASP.NET Core 5.0.**

According to your description, I conducted a test, first tested under windows, it was normal. Then deployed and tested under Linux, it is normal.

**I guess the reasons may be the following two:**

1. There is a problem with your .Net 5.0 installation. It may be used when compiling, if necessary, and cause compilation exception and release failure. (The possibility is relatively low)
2. It is possible that the webapi created by default does not have a default index page, so you feel that it is not supported. In fact, you can use webapp for testing, or you can write an interface for testing yourself.

**The VS2019 version I used for testing is `Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.8.2`. And I installed .net 5.0 Runtime on the machine.**

[image]

[image]

**For your question, describe in detail the steps of testing under Linux:**

Step 1. Create Core5.0 Webapi Project.

[image]

Step 2. Test in local, and it works fine.

[image]

Step 3. Deploy to azure with `Deployment` mode is `Framework-dependent`.

[image]

And test it, it look likes something wrong because the project don't set default route, and I input the `WeatherForecast` to access default interface, it works.

[image]

Step 4. Deploy to azure with `Deployment` mode is `Self-Contained` like you pic.

[image]

And it also works fine.

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that all paths to my web api return `404` besides the index which returns that microsoft page.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian  Does my answer help you? Do you have any other help?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian I don't know how you created your .net 5 web application. According to my test, you can clearly see that azure is supported, right.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian If you need further help, I hope you can use it to create a new demo project (no confidential information, just for testing your environment) and upload it to git.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian If you can, I hope you can accept my answer, because from the animated gif picture, we can be sure that azure is supported. As for the problem with your webapp, we can further discover the problem and solve it.

Comment: Indeed your sample works.I have tried my application as self-contained and framework dependant to no avail.All requests issued return a `404` whereas the default `index` page works.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian I still recommend using web mvc to create applications. In the mvc project, it is also coded to achieve the function like the webapi project, and the mvc will have its own page.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian I created webapi according to your description and found that swagger ui is automatically integrated. I believe it may be that this part is not yet compatible on azure. It should be possible to configure the default page.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian The current post problem has been processed. If you have a new problem or need this, you can repost another post about the problem of creating a webapi project in .net 5 and not being able to access `https://sitename.azurewebsites.net/swagger/index.html` normally.