# ASP NET Core 5.0 not supported in Azure WebApp Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-5.0

As part of the [build applications with Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/build-applications-with-azure-devops/) learning path, I have to deploy a .NET 5.0 [app](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/mslearn-tailspin-spacegame-web-deploy) to the Azure WebApp Service. When setting up the instance, I [no longer have .NET 5.0 available as an option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWQJs.png), only .NET 6.0.

I have no experience and only basic programming skills, so I naively tried to build it on .NET 6.0 with no success. I reported the error to MS Learning, but the available channels to communicate with them are one way and I have no feedback on whether a fix will be implemented at any of the ends.

What are my options?
Is it viable to refactor to .NET 6.0?
Any leads to MS Learning on the issue?
Is there a way I'm not seeing to select .NET 5.0 like via az CLI or any other?

Thank you in advance for the help, and since these are my first questions I'm sorry if I skipped a guideline or etiquette. I will appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way I'm not seeing to select .NET 5.0 like via az CLI or
> any other?

One of the workaround to use ASP.NET 5 ,Once you have created App service you can download the extension .

***GO TO APPSERVICE> EXTENSION> ADD> search ASP.NET5(32/64bit based on requirement) > Agree the policy> OK.***

Then you will be see *ASP.NET CORE 5* is there by navigating to ***ADVANCE TOOLS(KUDU CONSOLE)***

**BELOW ARE THE SCREENSHOT FOR REFERENCE:-**

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

[image]

- Click the "+" mark and go ahead and install the runtime in the app service. Then restart the site.

- *To create ASP.NET CORE 6 Application and deploy to AZURE* Please refer this [***MICROSFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=netcore-cli)

For more information please refer the below links:-

- [***Blog Post|To run .net5 in Azure***](https://kontext.tech/article/520/run-net-5-on-azure-app-services)
- [***SO THREAD|ASP NET Core 5.0 not supported in Azure***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129555/asp-net-core-5-0-not-supported-in-azure)